# Link Google tokens with FCM Registration tokens

Tags: php, android, firebase, token, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm currently building a PHP server to send notifications to my users that are registered. They have to log in with Google login method to obtain their tokens and send them to my database.

The problem is that Firebase only send notifications with register tokens.

My question is, how do I link those registered tokens with users google tokens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With registration token I assume you mean the Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) tokens.

Simply store the FCM token in the SharedPreferences when it is retrieved in your app and send it to your server when your user logged in or registered.

Comment: Thank you, I Think that will be the solution for my doubts. Im a begginer using firebase.